# Loading a text file of values into a list of lists

Tags: haskell

I have a text file (data.txt) that looks like this:

```
--#--
--#-@
-----
```

This is a MAP where (-) is places I can go, (#) is a wall, and (@) is my goal. I want to load this into a list of lists so that I can index it via (row,col) and then traverse it (unless there is a better way, I am a newb here).

I am using readFile but this gives it to me all in one shot, trying to use .lines to break it up but that still won't work ...

I was hoping to end up with something like this:

```
myMap = [[-,-,#,-,-],[-,-,#,-,@],[-,-,-,-,-]]
```

Unless I am mistaken this would let me do stuff like myMap !! 0 !! 0 to get [-] which is the CHAR at cell (0,0) on my map (and so forth).

Then with this I could pass it into a function and determine what moves I can do (not move into a wall obviously) and try to find some way to recursively move until I get to my (@), etc...

Comment: How does it not work? What error messages? What have you tried?

Comment: "trying to use lines to break it up but that still won't work" I can confirm that using `lines` will indeed split a string where newline characters occur. You should include your code in your question.

Comment: lines worked, I was using it incorrectly ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to load a string into a two-dimensional map. You can do something like:

```
import Data.Map hiding (map)

toMap :: String -> Map (Int,Int) Char
toMap = fromList . concatMap (λ(r,line) -> map (λ(c,char) -> ((r,c),char)) $ zip [0..] $ line) . zip [0..] . lines
```

and then use it:

```hs
raw :: String
raw = "--#--λn--#-@λn-----"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let myMap = toMap raw
  putStrLn $ "Map is: " ++ show myMap
  putStrLn $ "Elem in pos (0,0): " ++ show (myMap ! (0,0))
```